# Intuition for uniform continuity of a function on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know the definitions and examples and differences theoretically about continuity and uniform continuity. Can I tell if a function is uniformly continuous intuitively just by looking at the graph? For example how could I tell that $1/x$ is not uniformly continuous but $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is?

Comment: What's your domain, some interval $X$ such that $0\notin X$ but $0\in\overline X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform continuity is somewhat related to bounded derivative. It's not *quite* the same, of course. For one thing, a uniformly continuous function doesn't even have to be differentiable. And also, there are functions, like the cube root, which has unbounded derivative (and even undefined derivative at the origin), yet they are uniformly continuous.

Here is (what I can consciously conjure right now from) my personal intuition for looking at a function and making an informed guess as to whether they are uniformly continuous:

- A differentiable function with bounded derivative is always uniformly continuous (if $M$ is that bound, picking $\delta = \varepsilon/M$ will work, by the mean value theorem)
- A differentiable function with unbounded derivative (and possibly isolated points without a derivative), but which doesn't use that "infinite" derivative to actually *change much in value*, is still likely uniformly continuous (see the cube root function, compared to counterexamples like $\frac1x$, or $\sin(1/x)$, or $x^2$, or $\sin(x^2)$)
- A non-differentiable continuous function that's "close enough" to one of the above categories that you can make it into one of them by just "smoothing out" a little roughness is also likely uniformly continuous (the absolute value function is probably the most immediate example, but there are many more)
- A function that converges towards a limit (or even towards any straight line) as $x\to \infty$ and as $x\to-\infty$ will be "eventually uniformly continuous", as in if there are any obstructions to uniform continuity, they must be your usual (non-uniform) discontinuities, or holes in the domain, at specific points (consider $x^2$, which doesn't have a limit, where the obstruction to uniform continuity is towards $\pm \infty$, and on the other hand $\sin(1/x)$, which does have a limit towards $\pm \infty$, where the obstruction happens at the origin, as it must by this point)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, as you pointed out I made an error I meant the function 1/(1+x^2) so I edited it.

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite" derivative to actually change much in value?

Comment: @MojoTop Look at the examples I list. They all have unbounded derivatives (and the cube root even has infinite derivative, if you allow something like that). But apart from the cube root, all the other examples use this huge derivative to actually change a lot in value (in the case of the sine functions, change faster and faster back and forth between $-1$ and $1$, but still). On the other hand, the cube root function doesn't do that. It moves once across the $x$ axis with infinite slope, and then "calms down" again.

Comment: I see now. I think this is a very good and interesting intuitive approach as I will analyze it more thorough with time. Thank you for the beautiful answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my real analysis course, I came across the following exercise.

> **Exercise**
>
> (a) Let $f: A \to \mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous and suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$. Prove that $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence.
>
> (b) Let $g: (a, b) \to \mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous. Prove that there is a continuous function $\tilde g: [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ such that $\tilde g(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in (a, b)$, i.e., prove that it is possible to extend $g$ to a continuous function on $[a, b]$ by defining values of $g$ at $a$ and $b$.
>
> (c) Explain why a continuously extendable function $g: (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ must be uniformly continuous.

*Remark:* This exercise illustrates the essence of uniform continuity: uniformly continuous functions are exactly the ones that can be extended to continuous functions on closed sets. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Relations_with_the_extension_problem) has a nice discussion on this topic.

I encourage you to complete this exercise to build your own understanding.

---

For your examples, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is defined on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ which is not a closed set and it cannot be extended continuously to its closure $\mathbb R$ either. However, $g(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and can be continuously extended to its closure $\mathbb R$ by setting $g(0) = 1$.

Comment: This is only about functions that are uniformly continuous (or not) on a bounded set. It fails to capture that, for instance, $x^2$ is _not_ uniformly continuous on the real numbers.

Comment: @Arthur Sure, but this is an exercise to build intuition which is why it considers a simplified case. One can easily extend the argument to work for unbounded domains.

Comment: I don't see how this can be "easily extended" to unbounded domains in a way that makes $x^2$ fail yet $x$ succeed to be uniformly continuous. But maybe I am just not seeing some clever trick.

Comment: @Arthur I think I understand what you mean now. You are correct that this does not explain why $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous. I guess $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on any dense subset is one explanation, but you would still require an explanation of why that is the case which this answer does not give. However, I think this still provides intuition for why we care about uniform continuity.

Comment: To explain why $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, I would draw a picture of the definition. For every vertical radius $\epsilon > 0$, we require a constant horizontal radius $\delta > 0$ such that if a box of height $2\epsilon$ and width $2\delta$ is centred at a point on the graph, the graph will not penetrate the top or bottom of the box. The picture would be akin to the animations and visualisations found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity). As you mention, the derivative of $x^2$ is unbounded so such a $\delta$ does not exist.